# Using Disqus with cordova (Login not working)

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, disqus

I've a problem using disqus in my cordova/angularjs mobile app.

My app needs to open a blog page and shows comments using disqus.

Checking on StackOverfolow, Google and Disqus's website I found this tutorial (https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472096) that I followed.

First I created a static page to open comments like this one https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/mobile/js/mobiletemplate.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="disqus_thread">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var params;
        var disqus_url;
        var disqus_title;
        var disqus_shortname;
        var disqus_identifier;
        window.onload = function () {
            var match,
            pattern = /\+/g,
            search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
            decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pattern, " ")); },
            query = window.location.search.substring(1);
            params = {};
            while (match = search.exec(query))
                params[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
            if (params["shortname"] === undefined || params["url"] === undefined || params["title"] === undefined) {
                alert("Required arguments missing");
            }
            else {
                loadComments(params["shortname"], params["url"], params["title"], params["identifier"]);
            }
        };
        function loadComments(shortname, url, title, identifier) {
            disqus_url = url;
            disqus_title = title;
            disqus_shortname = shortname;
            if (identifier !== undefined)
                disqus_identifier = identifier;
            else
                disqus_identifier = "";
            (function() {
                var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = false;
                dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
                (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
            })();
        }
    </script>
    <noscript>
        Please enable JavaScript to view the
        <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">
            comments powered by Disqus.
        </a>
    </noscript>
    <a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">
        blog comments powered by
        <span class="logo-disqus">
            Disqus
        </span>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I open the page above using Cordova In App Browser (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) and I handle the login like suggested in the tutorial

```
$cordovaInAppBrowser.open($scope.dsqUrl, '_blank', options).then(function(event) {
            $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event) {
                console.log(event);
                if (event.url === 'http://disqus.com/next/login-success/') {
                   console.log("Login OK");
                    $cordovaInAppBrowser.open($scope.dsqUrl, '_blank', options).then(function(event) {
                        // success
                    }).catch(function(event) {
                        // error
                    });
                };
            });
        }).catch(function(event){ 
           //error
        });
```

The result is:

- open the comments page

[image]

- click on login
- fill the login form

[image]

- redirect (automatically) to the comments page

[image]

Now I've to be able to comment, but the comments page ask me to login another time....

[image]

If I try to login, because the cookies, the page knows that I've already logged in and redirect to comments page

The problem is that the comments page ask me always to login.
If I click on profile button it opens correctly my profile so the login has been done successfully

[image]

The same issue if I close the comments page and I reopen it

Do you know how can I fix this issue?

Thank you very much in advance
Michele Riso

Comment: Still no solutions for this issue.... Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same issue, any help? Thank you!